# CPQ Quote Draft Button

Tags: cpq

I am looking to add a button or even a look up in the quote line editor. So let's say I want to go back and forth between quotes without going back to the quote object screen. I only want to do this in the quote line editor. I want to also be able to create multiple quotes and navigate through them in the quote line editor through tabs or a button.

Is there even a way to see all my quote drafts in the quote line editor?

Any recommendations?